# Random crashes in custom NSOperation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, key-value-observing

Using iOS 4.3 on an ipad app

I have a custom NSOperation that uses an http request to process fragments of xml the operations are used in an NSOperationQueue. For the most part the app runs fine but, especially when tested on device the app crashes, this is always on a background/separate thread to the main thread. I've had this manifest itself as various errors including the infamous

```
warning: check_safe_call: could not restore current frame
```

ive pared back my code and discovered that the start method in my operation appears to be the culprit.

```
-(void)start
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    self.handledElements = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"el1", @"el2", @"el3", nil];


    if (![NSThread isMainThread])
        {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(start) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        return;
    }

        // problem is here !!
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    _isExecuting = YES;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];

    context = xmlCreatePushParserCtxt(&simpleSAXHandlerStruct, self, NULL, 0, NULL);

    if(_urlIsRelative == YES){
        self.request = [[MyHttpRequest alloc] initWithRelativeUrl:self.url andDelegate:self];
    }
    else {
        self.request = [[MyHttpRequest alloc] initWithAbsoluteUrl:self.url andDelegate:self];
    }

    self.characterBuffer = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    [self.request startRequest];



    [pool drain];
 }
```

the offending line appears to be the willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting" if i remove the lines related to KVO i cannot get the app to crash at all, if i add them back in i get random errors that always seem to point to getting the key value observance count. Although my app works, i would rather the start method was written as expected, with the KVO notifications take care of by me, any ideas??

Comment: i have a singleton class that observes outputs from each operation

Comment: Doesn't the NSOperation already take care of the isExecuting flag and KVO operations? I do not understand why you need those lines.

Comment: Have you overriden `- (BOOL)isExecuting`?

Comment: when implementing a custom NSOperation you override the start method, it is then your responsibility to issue isExecuting KVO updates see here -> http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: i have overridden -(BOOL)isExecuting as i say the app operates fine for random periods of time, then fails with this seemingly being the cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been an issue with libxml, i have updated my version and the problem has now gone away...

Answer (score 1):

> i have a singleton class that observes
>   outputs from each operation – Matt 38
>   mins ago

.... and that singleton is fully concurrent-safe for the isExecuting change notifications (observations)?

Comment: What does the state change of `isExecuting` do?

Comment: it informs my singleton that the operation has started